# Twig extensions for shortening text?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, word-wrap

What I'm looking for is something that limits the output without breaking tags. Let's say that I have some content for example coming from FCK / MCE:

```
<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  </p>

<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem </p>

<p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem </p>
```

Now for example if I did something like `{{ output|raw[:10] ~ '...' }}`I would get:

```
<p>lorem i...
```

But instead I would like to get:

```
<p>lorem i...</p>
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: `{{ output|raw[:10] ~ '...' }} <p>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try available extension of twig to truncate text in Twig & Symfony2.

Your text is in html so first get plain text using "striptags" filter then apply "truncate" filter of twig.

```
<p>{{ output|striptags|truncate(50, true) }}</p>
```

but first you must enable Twig-Text-Extension as following

```
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text());
```

or in symfony2

```
// app/config/config.yml
services:
    twig.extension.text:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Following is available options for truncate filter

1 - only truncate

```
<p>{{ output|striptags|truncate(50) }}</p>
```

2 - Set second parameter if you want to preserve whole words.

```
<p>{{ output|striptags|truncate(50, true) }}</p>
```

3 - Set third parameter if you want use your own separator instead of "..."

```
<p>{{ output|striptags|truncate(50, true, ".........") }}</p>
```

for more detail about twig text extension visit http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/text.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it starts with `<p>` and ends with `</p>` use this:

```
{{ output|raw[:10] ~ '...' }}</p>
```

If you want to find and replace something in your output you can

```
<p>{{ (output|replace({'<p>': '', '</p>': ''}))|raw[:10] ~ '...' }}</p>
```

Comment: In the first post I mentioned that the output might come from MCE / FCK so I basically don't know if it's gonna be <p> or <h1> or even <img> tag. So that's not any kind of solution.

Comment: Oh I see, so in this case you need something like parser to parse whatever comes from MCE/FCK and convert to content you want. You can use `matches` in tiwg to build it with expression [http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#expressions](Expression in Symfony)

Comment: Do not forget autoescape for security reasons: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html

Comment: If he auto-escapes, he will display tags instead of intepreting them. As soon as he is using `|raw`, I guess the goal is to display the content as it is (and security had been made at controller side, using [html purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) or such).